GASからのグループ設定でエラーが発生するようになった(whoCanViewMembership = "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_VIEW)
症状
以前からGoogleAppsScriptで実行していたグループ作成のコードでエラーがでるようになりました。
エラーはグループのメンバーリストを表示できるユーザーを"組織内のすべてのメンバー"に設定する箇所です。
2024年4月末までエラー発生なし、5月に入ってからエラーが発生します。
組織の設定等は変更した記憶はありません。
エラーメッセージ
Failed request validation in update settings: WHO_CAN_VIEW_MEMBERSHIP_CANNOT_BE_BROADER_THAN_WHO_CAN_SEE_GROUP

エラー箇所
whoCanViewMembership = "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_VIEW";

試したこと
エラーとなるところを"ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW";に変更するとエラー発生はなくなる
ただし、他ユーザーからメンバーが見れなくなるため解決ではない
質問事項
①以前と動作が異なっているのは仕様変更でしょうか
②「グループを表示できるユーザー」に組織の管理が影響しているようなメッセージ表示がありますが、関係する設定箇所はあるのでしょうか
③「グループを表示できるユーザー」GASから設定する方法が見つかりませんでしたが、設定することは可能でしょうか
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups?hl=ja
④解決法をご教示ください
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();s
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

//実行メニューを作成
function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var menu = ui.createMenu("GAS実行");
 menu.addItem("Googleグループ一括作成", "createGoogleGroup");
 menu.addToUi();
}

function createGoogleGroup() {
 var lastColum = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var startRow = 2;  
 var numRows = lastRow - 1;   
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColum);
 var data = dataRange.getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var row = data[i];

  row.rowNumber = i + 2;

  //Result列がブランクであれば処理を実行   
  if (!row[3]) { 
   var result = "";

   try
   {
    //Groupの作成（コメントアウトすることでGroupのプロパティ更新のみ実行可能）
    AdminDirectory.Groups.insert({email: row[0], name: row[1], description: row[2]});   

    //Groupのプロパティ更新
    var group = AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get(row[0]);

    //グループのメンバーリストを表示できるユーザーを "組織内のすべてのメンバー" に設定
    //group.whoCanViewMembership = "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW"; ※こちらの設定に変更するとエラー発生はなくなります
    group.whoCanViewMembership = "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_VIEW";

    //グループのメッセージを表示できるユーザーを "すべてのメンバー" に設定
    group.whoCanViewGroup = "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW";

    //グループにメッセージを投稿できるユーザーを "誰でも" に設定
    group.whoCanPostMessage = "ANYONE_CAN_POST";

    //グループのメンバーを管理できるユーザーを "オーナーと管理者" に設定
    group.whoCanModerateMembers = "OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS";

    //グループに参加できるユーザー "招待されたユーザーのみ"に設定
    group.whoCanJoin = "INVITED_CAN_JOIN";

    //グループから脱退できるユーザーを "誰も" に設定
    group.whoCanLeaveGroup = "NONE_CAN_LEAVE";

    //グループを検索できるユーザーを "すべてのメンバー" に設定
    group.whoCanDiscoverGroup = "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_DISCOVER";

    //グループをアーカイブする
    group.isArchived = "true";

    //スパムに対するグループのモデレーションレベルを "許可する" に設定
    group.spamModerationLevel = "ALLOW";

    //グループに対して共同トレイを有効にしたままにする
    group.enableCollaborativeInbox = "true";

    //メンバーはグループとしてメッセージを投稿できます
    group.membersCanPostAsTheGroup = "true";

    //デフォルトの差出人
    group.defaultSender = "GROUP";

    //コンテンツを管理できるユーザーを設定
    group.whoCanModerateContent = "ALL_MEMBERS"

    //メタデータを管理できるユーザーを指定
    group.whoCanAssistContent = "ALL_MEMBERS"

    // 共有ラベル設定を有効にする
    group.enableSharedLabels = true;

    AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.patch(group, row[0]);

    result = "Success"; 
   }catch(e){
    result = "Error:" + e;
   }

   //実行結果をResult列にセット
   sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, 4).setValue(result); 

  }
 }  
}


本質問は自己解決しました。
「グループを検索できるユーザーを "すべてのメンバー" に設定」としていたものが、
"組織内のすべてのメンバー" へ設定する必要があるということが判明しました。
【変更前】
group.whoCanDiscoverGroup = 'ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_DISCOVER'

【変更後】
group.whoCanDiscoverGroup = 'ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_DISCOVER'

メンバーリストを表示できるユーザーが組織内となっているのに
検索できるユーザーが組織ではない、矛盾から生じているエラーのようでした。
